# How to return a dictionary or array if dict is mixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my python function code:

```py
def checkId(user):
    members = {932922669: {'naam':'Mike','account':'A1'} , 932922668: naam':'Alfred','account':'A2'}}    
    if user in members.keys():
        return dict(members)[user['naam'][account]
    else:
        return False
```

I would like to check if id 9329222669 exists in this dict. If yes, return name and account, else return False.

Comment: You sample has a syntax error: add { after 932922668:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need

```
def checkId(user):
    members = {932922669: {'naam':'Mike','account':'A1'} , 932922668: {'naam':'Alfred','account':'A2'}}    
    if user in members:
        return tuple(members[user].values())
    return False

print(checkId(932922669))  # ('Mike', 'A1')
print(checkId(0000))       # False
```